# Using USB CDMA dongle with USB extension cable goes into cable unplugged loop. Need help

Tags: usb, internet

I'm using ZTE AC3633 cdma dongle which gives me internet over EVDO network. If I connect the dongle direct to the macbook pro its working fine, but sometimes signal drops and have to go out and fetch the signal. For this I thought If I use USB extension cable (1.5 meter) and hang the dongle outside my window then it picks up good signal and gives me good speeds. But unfortunately its not working as it keep on saying "Cable unplugged" and it stays in loop. But If I use the dongle with power adapter using the same cable then I can connect to dongle wifi. I have done some research and came to know might be voltage or current drop and not sure where its happening and what to do. If I use powered usb hub will it be okay for data?

Also I have got the cheap china made usb hub ripped off.But didn't check whether I can do modifications on it to use it for both power and data.

Please help me with this and advice me on devices that needs to be purchased to ovecome the problem.

Comment: If the dongle has a connector for it you might look into getting an external antenna.

Comment: @JanDorniak no it does not have a connector for external antenna.

Comment: Might be the cable is faulty or of low quality try another one.

Comment: @RogUE I have tested the cable by ripping of both the ends and used multimeter to test the continuity and resistance. Everything ok.

Comment: I haven't tested one so I can't give any figures for conductivity&resistance. But I have seen instances where a cheap cable disconnects itself frequently

Comment: @RogUE Yes you're right. But I'm not 100% sure about my cable quality. I have to see whether I can find a high quality cable and compare it.

Comment: Have you tried connecting other usb devices to the cable? If yes, did they work as expected? You could also try by changing the usb port.

Comment: Yes I tried usb flash drive, external hard disk and wired mouse. In that usb flash drive and mouse are working, external hard disk is flashing continuously but not recognised on pc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34085/discussion-between-i0s-and-rogue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much both JanDorniak and RogUE for joining me here and answering my question.

As suspected it was the cable fault. I now got the new 1.5 meters USB 3.0 Extension cable from Amazon Basics which is own brand of Amazon.com. I was truly surprised by seeing the quality of the cable and was perfect match for my requirement. Also I bought one USB 3.0 based 4 port HUB with power adapter and using it whenever I hook power hungry devices.

So I advice who ever come across same problem please first try testing your cable by hooking high power consuming devices and see If its capable of delivering the data and power. If not then buy good quality USB 3.0 cable, remember not the USB 2.0 one because its got half the power of USB 3.0.

Now my next project is to have a BiQUAD Antenna to my CDMA Dongle and improve my signal strength. I will post it online If I'm successful in seeing results.

Thank you all :)